# Wifi access point no internet connection

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, raspberry-pi, wireless-access-point

**Situation**
There's a intranet with access to the internet. However, you can only gain access to this network, and therefore the internet, if your device has a whitelisted MAC address. This is no problem though, as you can easily use a MAC changer to bypass this barrier by using one of the already whitelisted addresses.

**Goal**
As this network is only accessable through a wired connection, a Raspberry Pi shall be used to make a wireless connection available. Thus the RPi needs to be connected to the mentioned network and is supposed to work as a WLAN access point.

**RPi configuration**
The RPi (3 Model B) is running Raspbian as OS. To create the AP, I'm using `hostapd`. And to for the DNS and the DHCP stuff, I'm using `dnsmasq`.
I won't list all the steps I did to get a working configuration, but if you want to get an idea of it, I used the following (<strike>here and here</strike>) tutorials (they're in German, but at least, you can see the used commands, sorry).
However, the current configuration seems to be correct to some extend, as I can successfully use it at home without any issues.

**Problem**
Altough I'm able to connect to the RPi with my laptop or my smartphone, I have no internet connection.
Connected to the RPi via SSH (using `PuTTY`), there's no answer when pinging `google.com` (or `8.8.8.8`).

**Things that are working and possible solutions**
First of all, I got this *setup* (with a slightly different configuration I'm not aware of anymore, damn it) *working once*. Also I'm able to connect to the network and the internet with a spoofed MAC using my laptop. The accessablility of websites varies using different browsers though (best one seems to be `IE`/`Edge`).

*Things that are already working:*

- RPi (`eth0`) gets an IP address.
- One can connect to the AP with his/her smartphone.
- `google.com` gets resolved to an IP (`172.217.21.110` for example).
- The spoofed MAC address is used to send data packages (observed with `tshark`).

*Possible solutions that didn't work out/solve the problem:*

- Configuring the correct time on the RPi.
- Pinging an IP instead of a domain (in case of a failing DNS resolution).
- Changed the MAC of `eth0` (RPi's wired connection) to several different whitelisted ones (using `macchanger` and `/etc/network/interfaces`).
- Used different ethernet ports to connect to the given network.
- Changing the configuration file of `dnsmasq` (i.e. `server`, `dhcp-option`, etc.).
- Setting up a the whole system (and configuration) a second time (not on purpose, happend due to a failing SD card) *(The first setup was installed through the NOOBS setup while the second one was installed via the lite version of Raspbian)*.

**EDIT**
Stupid as I am, I never actually took a look into `/var/log/syslog`.
While going through it, I found that often there's a reply from `dnsmasq` looking like this: `reply geo-prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com is <CNAME>` after `wlan0` is activated and working.
May the [rest of the log](http://pastebin.com/tiY3FRz5) help to solve this issue.

---

To me the whole situation just seems kind of weird right now, because every single part of the whole thing is working, just not as one system. *(The current configuration is working at home and I have access to the network and the internet with a spoofed MAC address using my laptop)*.
I hope, anybody of you can help me out with this one, as I have no more ideas left how to get this working. Maybe someone of you has ran into any kind of similar issue once.
**What may be configured badly in my case? Do I miss something? Is there any plausible explanation why it worked once and now, without any major changes, doesn't?**
**I greatly appreciate your help!**

---

***In case I missed any detail about the situation/configuration that's necessary to solve this problem, just ask me in the comments.***